# Reading all files from a directory

Tags: python, directory

Following code is to read all files in download directory,but when i execute this code it won't print(display), what is wrong with this code..?

```
import glob   
path = '/home/mypc/download/*.html'   
files=glob.glob(path)   
for file in files:     
    f=open(file, 'r')  
    f.readlines()   
    f.close()
```

Comment: Can It be migrated to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `readlines()` method of a file object returns a Python list. It does not automatically write on stdout the contents of the file: Python is a scripting language, but not a shell scriping language!

You should replace:

```
f.readlines()
```

with:

```
sys.stdout.write(f.read())
```

Note that I'm using `read()` instead of `readlines()`. As I said, `readlines()` returns a list, but here we want to print a string -- and `read()` does what we want: it reads the whole file and returns a string. It's not optimal when the file is huge (because it will use a huge amount of memory), but it works.

It's worth noting that you code is flawed. You said: *following code is to read all files in download directory*. Your code actually will attempt to read both files and directories ending with `.html`. If your code finds a directory ending with `.html`, it will loudly crash.

Lastly, you should prefer using the `with` statement when opening files, especially when you are opening many files. The `with` statement will ensure that the file is closed as soon as you have finished working with it, even if an error occurs.

Therefore your code should look like this:

```
import sys
import glob
import errno

path = '/home/mypc/download/*.html'   
files = glob.glob(path)   
for name in files: # 'file' is a builtin type, 'name' is a less-ambiguous variable name.
    try:
        with open(name) as f: # No need to specify 'r': this is the default.
            sys.stdout.write(f.read())
    except IOError as exc:
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR: # Do not fail if a directory is found, just ignore it.
            raise # Propagate other kinds of IOError.
```

Answer (score 4):

You may want to use at least one `print`. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob   
path = '/home/mypc/download/*.html'   
files=glob.glob(path)   
for file in files:     
    f=open(file, 'r')  
    print '%s' % f.readlines()   
    f.close()
    #if you want to print only the filenames, use 'print file' instead of three previous lines
```

And please read some documentation about [Input and Output in Python](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Answer (score 1):

I you want to display the file names you need to use the print command

```
import glob   
path = '/home/mypc/download/*.html'   
files=glob.glob(path)   
for file in files: 
    print file
```

Answer (score 1):

You have only written code to read the files, not to print the contents. If that is what you want to do you can replace

```
f.readlines()
```

with:

```
for line in f:
    print line
```

Hope that helps.